# Building docker image task results in VSTS error

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, docker, azure-devops

I'm following 
[this Microsoft tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wael-kdouh/2018/01/02/deploying-your-dockerized-angular-application-to-azure-using-vsts/#comment-835) on how to containerize and deploy an Angular application on Azure using Docker.

I'm running into a unique issue that is not addressed in the tutorial. Every time the build reaches the `build an image` task it fails with the following error.

```
2018-01-29T12:37:28.3169577Z [command]/usr/local/bin/docker build -f 
/opt/vsts/work/1/s/Dockerfile -t iponam.azurecr.io/my-angular-app:197 
/opt/vsts/work/1/s
2018-01-29T12:37:28.7630517Z Sending build context to Docker daemon 
593.4 kB
2018-01-29T12:37:28.7639048Z 
2018-01-29T12:37:28.7859042Z Step 1/3 : FROM nginx
2018-01-29T12:37:30.3172506Z latest: Pulling from library/nginx
2018-01-29T12:37:30.3188560Z e7bb522d92ff: Pulling fs layer
2018-01-29T12:37:30.3204163Z 6edc05228666: Pulling fs layer
2018-01-29T12:37:30.3219390Z cd866a17e81f: Pulling fs layer
2018-01-29T12:37:30.3279280Z cd866a17e81f: Download complete
2018-01-29T12:37:30.3294450Z e7bb522d92ff: Verifying Checksum
2018-01-29T12:37:30.3310189Z e7bb522d92ff: Download complete
2018-01-29T12:37:30.3511653Z 6edc05228666: Verifying Checksum
2018-01-29T12:37:30.3529571Z 6edc05228666: Download complete
2018-01-29T12:37:32.1518557Z e7bb522d92ff: Pull complete
2018-01-29T12:37:33.4982718Z 6edc05228666: Pull complete
2018-01-29T12:37:33.6163338Z cd866a17e81f: Pull complete
2018-01-29T12:37:33.6365600Z Digest: 
sha256:285b49d42c703fdf257d1e2422765c4ba9d3e37768d6ea83d7fe2043dad6e63d
2018-01-29T12:37:33.6540818Z Status: Downloaded newer image for 
nginx:latest
2018-01-29T12:37:33.6558500Z  ---> 3f8a4339aadd
2018-01-29T12:37:33.6577887Z Step 2/3 : COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
2018-01-29T12:37:33.6595536Z COPY failed: stat 
/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder545265281/dist: no such file or 
directory
2018-01-29T12:37:33.6780204Z ##[error]COPY failed: stat 
/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder545265281/dist: no such file or 
directory
2018-01-29T12:37:33.6855716Z ##[error]/usr/local/bin/docker failed with
return code: 1
```

Per the tutorial, this is running on a hosted linux agent that I cannot access to examine folder structure. Essentially what's happening is my `Dockerfile` (below) is pulling an nginx image, building the angular application with `ng build prod` and then I try to `COPY` the `dist` folder into the `/usr/share/nginx/html`. Here's the Dockerfile, it's identical to the one in the tutorial as well:

```
FROM nginx
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

I have spent countless hours trying to debug and understand the issue. Any help will be tremendously appreciated. Thank you!

**Update**

After `run build` is executed successfully I don't see where the `dist` directory is outputted to. I checked every single place on the machine with no luck. On my local machine the `dist` will appear in the root of the project folder.

Comment: The dist folder is the build output directory (outDir in .angular-cli.json), so the folder will be generated during npm task (npm run build). Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true)

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT thank you for your help. I added the logs to this google drive link because I do not have a non-work MSFT account. Thank you! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hcBeBVjac1i1jlhTtQIPtJX_M3MGflaV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is there .angular-cli.json file in repository? What's the value of outDir? You can specify the output path in command (Check my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this command instead in NPM build task (Command and arguments):

`run build -- -op dist`

Comment: That did it. I just had to modify it to look like `run build --prod -op dist` Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

okay, first off all, you can examine the folder structure, you can add a Shell script step before docker build and do something like `ls -Rla`, which is a hack, undoubtebly, but a working one.

As for you error, it indicates that there is no such file (`dist`) under the working directory. Again, what you could do is verify this file is in the root of the repo or use the `ls` hack to locate the file. You should also check that you didnt change the default working directory of the `docker build` step. If you did you need to specify path to `dist` file relative to the working directory.